# Why is the my pattern attribute not working the way it should?

Tags: html, regex

```
<form id="pattern-form">
    <input type="search" name="search-input" pattern=".*[^2].*">
    <button formaction="lava.php">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The pattern is not working.

- `.*` = any character any amount.
- `[^2]` = the digit 2 is not allowed.
- `.*` = any character any amount.

What should happen is that you should be able to type any amount of any character as long as the digit 2 is not present. But that's not happening. I can submit any character any amount including the digit 2. I can type this `"gfgdgdg2"` and it gets submitted. Why? Or i can type this: `"2gfgfg"` and it gets submitted. Or `"gdgdg 2 gdgdg"` and again it gets submitted. Why?

If my pattern is `[^2].*` The way this works is if the first letter is digit 2, then it doesn't get submitted. But if you first type something, and then end with `"2"` then it gets submitted, which is understandable, that's why I've used any character any amount twice, at the front and back of the pattern. So why is it not working?

Comment: You're saying: match on anything, then don't match on 2, then match on anything. Anything includes 2, so it will match your entire string unless 2 is the first character in the string.

Comment: Basically, if you enter `212` the `[^2]` will match the `1`.

Comment: try out `[^2]+`  ==> at least 1 character + no 2 allowed

Comment: @MichaelBianconi Yes, but why is [^2] getting ignored? If i replace [^2] with [2]{2}, now it works. I have to add two digits of 2 somewhere, otherwise it's invalid. So why is adding 2 digits working, but banning a digit not working if its in the middle of the pattern?

Comment: @Ivar Why? Why is [^2] getting ignored?

Comment: @PatrickArtner It's not working if i have the "any amount of any character" at the beginning.

Comment: @IloveCoffee It isn't getting ignored. In `212`, the first `.*` matches the `2`, the `[^2]` matches the `1` and the last `.*` matches the `2` again. It fully matches your regex.

Comment: @IloveCoffee Don't add "any amount of any character"` Just `pattern="[^2]+"`.

Comment: @Ivar ahhhhh, i get it now. Yeah, that makes sense. But if i use only "[^2]+", doesn't that mean that 2 is banned only at the beginning, and not anywhere in the row?

Comment: [^2] means match exactly one character BUT 2 - with the + afterwards it matches 1 to any amount of any character but 2 - don't put any other stuf to the regex

Comment: @Ivar I just tested it, and it works exactly the way i wanted it. Could you explain to me why does it work this way? I mean, the pattern says that the first letter should not be 2. So why is it that the 2 is not allowed anywhere in the row?

Comment: @IloveCoffee See Patrick's comment. The pattern attribute in HTML matches the whole string. So if you would have `[^2]` you it would match any character except two, exactly one time. But by adding the `+` you say that that last class should be matched 1 or more times. Here is a visualization: https://regexper.com/#%5E%5B%5E2%5D%2B%24 (Added `^` and `$` for a better representation, but in the `pattern` attribute, they are not needed.)

Comment: @Ivar By "last class" you mean the last character, right? This is what confuses me. When i typed "[^2].*", the way this worked is that, the first letter must not be 2, but anything after that is allowed. So why does it not work the same way if i replace .* with + or just * ? Shouldn't it say that, only the first character must not be 2, and after that, anything is allowed?

Comment: By last class I mean the `[^2]`. Basically you `+` is saying that it could be `[^2]` or `[^2][^2]` or `[^2][^2][^2]` or any infinite number of this pattern, where each could be any character except the 2.

Comment: aah, i get it now. Thank you once again. By the way, + and * are essentially the same thing, correct?

Comment: No. `*` is zero or more, `+` is one or more. So `[^2]*` will also match an empty string. `[^2]+` will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```html
<form id="pattern-form">
    <input type="search" name="search-input" pattern="[\D013-9]*">
    <button formaction="lava.php">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Or just `[^2]*`.

Comment: @Ivar In your pattern, it means the first letter must not be "2". What i wanna do is to ban "2" regardless where it is in the row.

Comment: @iloveCoffee  Ivan means:  Any amount of characters OTHER then 2 - where "any" might also be 0 characters.

Comment: @IloveCoffee check out https://regexcrossword.com/  for easy gamified regex learning (no affiliation other then being a fan of it)

Comment: @PatrickArtner but what i am getting confused at is that, shouldn't "[^2]*" mean that, the first letter must not be 2, wheres the rest could be any?

Comment: @ILove  No, that would be `[^2].*` - the quantifier is always for the thing exactly before it - so `[^2]+`  meanst "Group of all things except 2" for 1_to_n  times

Answer (score 0):

`.*[^2].*` matches any string that contains at least one character that is not `2`. It will not match a string like `22222`. It will match `12222` because `1` is not `2`.

Use `[^2]*` to match any characters other than `2` zero or more times:

```css
input:valid {
  color: #000000;
}
input:invalid {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<form id="pattern-form">
    <input type="search" name="search-input" pattern="[^2]*">
    <button formaction="lava.php">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The HTML pattern always requires entire string to match, you do not need `^` and `$` anchors, but you still can use them, `pattern="^[^2]*$"` will work, too.